# Online list of novel lengths, in word-count

Tags: wordcount, book-length

I am looking for the most comprehensive list of novels arranged by size in terms of word-counts. For instance, how many words has *Lord of the Flies*, how many *Moby Dick*, how many *Lolita* (just to remain on anglo-american literature), and so on.

Does anybody know if such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few I found that have quite a lot of famous books on them:

http://commonplacebook.com/art/books/word-count-for-famous-novels/

https://indefeasible.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/great-novels-and-word-count/

Does that help at all?

Comment: That is very much what I needed at this stage, thank you. Also the links included in those pages help. My idea is to have a sort of recurring database, maybe built on wikidata, that performs that, but this is very useful for now. Thanks.